# When to hide comments under the “show comments” button?

Tags: comments

I’m designing a comment system for a magazine site. What is the best solution for showing comment section for newspaper / magazine?

My current structure of the article is like this:

- Header
- Content
- Share post
- Author
- Comments
- Related

Current options are:

## Show comments after the post in full

Pros:

- no additional action to show comments section is needed
- user won’t skip comments

Cons:

- takes a lot of space: you must show related before the comments
- comments loading time adds to the page load

## Partly hide comments under the button

This solution shows 1 or 2 (generally up to 5) comments, and then shows button

Pros:

- Takes considerable amount of space
- Not as easy skippable as a single button
- Allows to load other comments asynchronously later

Cons:

- You most likely need to use some voting system in place, otherwise visible comments may not be that interesting
- Requires additional action to view other comments

## Completely hide comments under the button

Show only button “Show n comments”, then load comments after the click.

Pros:

- Takes less space of all
- Allows to load other comments asynchronously later

Cons

- Easy skippable - may be no noticed at all
- Doesn’t invite user to participate

Are there any other pros and cons to these approaches? Second seems the best for me for now, but maybe I’m missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to make like Facebook do with their [Comments social plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/) : shows 1 or 2 (generally up to 5) comments, and then shows button.

I think [Disqus](https://disqus.com) makes the same too.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put a "Jump to comments" button in a good place. "The Guardian" has a nice (not perfect) solution to this, which is similar to your second option.

[image: The Guardian article header]

Featured comments (by humans not algorithms)

[image: The Guardian comments solution]